# How to perform a delete operation on a Model?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, eloquent, laravel-5

Coming from a Ruby on Rails experience where you load up the rails console to delete a user or all users. I am new to Laravel 5 and I am looking for something similar to delete a user already in the sqlite3 database.

I see where people are talking about `User::find(1)->delete();` to delete a user but where to you put that and run in? Is there a console to perform a delete task in? I would like to know how to delete a user without dropping the table. I do not want to soft delete.

Comment: If you want to do it on the console, you should write a [command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can put this code for example in controller.

You can use

```
$user = User::find($id);    
$user->delete();
```

if you don't use `SoftDeletingTrait` trait or

```
$user = User::find($id);    
$user->forceDelete();
```

if you do, and you want to really remove user from database, not just hide it from results.

More you can read at [Laravel page](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: Where in the controller to put that then do what next?

Comment: If you just want to remove the record that's it. You should really look at Laravel documentation if you want to write your project

Answer (score 8):

in Laravel 5 you can use the destroy method.

```
$user->destroy($id);
```

and, sure, you have a command line to do so.

```
$ php artisan tinker
```

and you can run for example

```
>> $var = new App\User;
>> $user= $user->find($id);
>> $user->destroy();
```

Answer (score 7):

Several ways to do this.

If your controller defines the user as an argument:

```
public function destroy(User $user) 
{
    return $user->delete();
}
```

You can also delete any user by $id:

```
User::destroy ($id);
```

Assuming you're wrapping these routes with some security.

*Edit: Corrected spelling*

Answer (score 4):

> You can use bellow example to delete data with multiple
>   parameters......

```
> 
> tableName::where('field_1','=',$para1)
>               ->where('field_2,'=',$para2)
>               ->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

This still works with laravel **7**, i use **tinker** command line and the delete() method:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Now i can run commands directly:

```
> App\User::find($id)->delete();
```